# Trying to create a Discord Welcome/Leave Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot that publicly and privately (via DM) welcomes a new user to a Discord server **AND** sends a message to the Moderator channel when a user leaves the server.

I can get the welcome dm and welcome message working, but when I add the code after #Mod Leave Announcement nothing happens.

```
import all necessary commands and libraries
import discord
import asyncio
import logging

@client.event
async def on_ready():
print('logged in as')
print(client.user.name)
print(client.user.id)
print('-----')
newUserDMMessage = "Welcome DM"

#Public Welcome
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " joined")
await client.send_message(member, newUserDMMessage)
await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='CHANNELID'), 'Welcome!')
print("Sent message to " + member.name)
print("Sent message about " + member.name + " to #CHANNEL")

#Mod Leave Announcement
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
print("Recognised that a member called " + member.name + " left")
await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='CHANNELID'), member.name + ' left')
print("Sent message to #CHANNEL")

client.run('Token')
```

Comment: Do you see any error message in the terminal you're running the bot from?  Does the "Moderator channel" have restricted access?  You could also try resolving the channel objects with `member.server.get_channel("CHANNEL_ID")` instead.

Comment: I don't get any errors. Without the #Mod Leave Announcement code, the bot runs fine, with the code the bot acts like nothing has happened.

I'll try member.server.get_channel("CHANNEL_ID") and see if that helps.

Comment: Could you double check your indentation here and make sure it's identical to the indentation of the file you're running?

Comment: The moderator channel does have restricted access, but the bot does have permission to see and post in there.

There are 4 spaces of indentation after each async def line. Should there be no indentation?

I'm new to python and still learning would `member.server.get_channel("CHANNEL_ID")` replace `client.send_message(discord.Object(id='CHANNEL_ID')`?

Comment: Indentation is [very important in Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-side_rule).  The reason I'm asking is to check that you didn't indent `client.run` as well, which would mean it's never executed.  (In future, when you have your code in the StackOverflow editor, you can highlight it and press Ctrl-K to auto indent it)

Comment: Thanks for the tip Patrick! Indenting like you said made both functions work. Weird that one did and one didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code that's working currently. Thanks to Patrick Haugh for all the tips.

```
# import all necessary commands and libraries
import discord
import asyncio
import logging

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('-----')

newUserDMMessage = "WELCOME!"

#Public Welcome
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    print("Recognized that " + member.name + " joined")
    await client.send_message(member, newUserDMMessage)
    await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='CHANNELID'), 'Welcome!')
    print("Sent message to " + member.name)
    print("Sent message about " + member.name + " to #CHANNEL")

#Mod Leave Announcement
@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    print("Recognized that " + member.name + " left")
    await client.send_message(discord.Object(id='CHANNELID'), '**' + member.mention + '** just left.')
    print("Sent message to #CHANNEL")

client.run('token')
```